# Pandas, sum specifics columns in a new column

Tags: python, pandas, sum

I have some columns that I want to sum in a new column

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 2 |

EXPECTED OUTPUT

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 2 | 5 |

Comment: `df['D'] = df[['A','B','C']].sum(axis=1)`.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] showing _code_ for what you've already tried based on your own research, and what went wrong with your attempts. Please note that this is not a code-writing or tutorial site, and we ask that you at least make an attempt to solve the problem so that we can offer specific advice and answers